# SQL Get New Record from Match Records

Tags: sql, group

I have a Table for Mutilate and Duplicate Records So I want Get New Duplicate Like `Group By`
I give the Example
My Table example

```
ID, Item   Rate
--------------
1  APPLE  10
2  ORANGE 15
3  BANANA 10
4  APPLE  12
5  APPLE  13
6  ORANGE 14
7  APPLE  20
8  MANGO  22
9  CHERRY 30
10 BANANA 25
```

then I want Get Like this

```
ID Item  Rate
--------------
7  APPLE   20
6 ORANGE  14
10 BANANA 25
8  MANGO  22
9  CHERRY 30
```

i have tried query like this

```
SELECT  MAX(ID)as ID, Item,Rate
FROM Sales 
GROUP BY  Item,Rate
```

Result is Poor

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Comment: Try this buddy! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group